getting autocomplete working with a cmake project in vscode for C/C++ and protobuf
I'm new to vscode and switching from eclipse.  I have a larger cmake project that I've imported into vscode. (just converted it from autotools to cmake) I have that working to configure/build/install fine.  This is on a Redhat 8 linux system.
I'm having trouble with C/C++ autocomplete and a few problems with includes.
I have installed C/C++ Intellisense, C/C++ extension pack and a protobuf extension (pbkit.dev).  I expected/hoped that a good working cmake import would automagically "find" everything the source needed for autocomplete, etc...  Doesn't seem to be the case.  I had the following problems which were leading to missing autocompletion hints:

#include <glib.h>  ->  cannot open source file error.
In my CMakeLists.txt, the include path for this is set/determined.  In eclipse, I had to explicitly add an include path for this, but was hoping I wouldn't have to here.

I fixed this by adding /usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include and /usr/include/glib-2.0 to includePath in c_cpp_properties.json.
Is this the best way to handle this?

#include myheader.h -> leads to "cannot open source file "google/protobuf/port_def.inc" which is referenced in additional includes.
The protobuf includes were defined in CMakeLists.txt.  So do I also have to add these to the include Paths or is there something in CMake that I can add to get vscode to automatically pick this up?

Adding the google/protobuf/include path and the glib.h paths fixes my autocomplete issues.  But was hoping for a better solution.
note:  Using a custom version of protobuf that is installed to a non-standard path. (/opt/)
I'm also curious as to what adding "compileCommands" to c_cpp_properties.json would do, as another post suggested this for fixing missing includes.  I do not have that line and for configuration provider I have ms-vscode.make-tools instead of ms-vscode.cmake-tools.  I thought I followed proper instructions for setting up cmake, but now I'm not sure...
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CMake",
            "compileCommands": "${config:cmake.buildDirectory}/compile_commands.json",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }

I'm still working through some vscode tutorials, so sorry if any of this should be more obvious.  Appreciate any feedback

Because there are different configurations for the Intellisense tools and the compiler, you have to repeat a bunch of stuff. Nothing you can do about it at this point other than use a different tool.

""compileCommands" to c_cpp_properties.json would do, as another post suggested this for fixing missing includes" that's nonsense. c_cpp_properties.json is not a compile commands database.

@super-starball-ultra  I wouldn't have thought so, which is why I was asking about it.  I didn't want to even start going through it.

I have everything working now, just not as smooth as I had hoped...
